# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib'

Tags: visual-c++, build, cmake

I build a project (C++ based) using CMAKE using Microsoft Visual Studio 9 compiler
(x64). This in return generated a solution file (.sln) for the project. My project is also using Boost library.

I opened the '.sln' file in Microsoft Visual Studio 9 and when I tried to build the project 
in Debug mode (x64). I received the following error:

```
 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib'
```

Can somebody please help about whats going on wrong here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you verified that you have the correct version of the Boost library? Also check you have included it in your Linker options!

Comment: @Paddyd yes I am using Boost 1.53 version with compiled with VC 64. I hope this is not a problem. Second, when I check the properties of my project, it does not show any Linker options. It shows only Common Properties and Configuration Properties. This is I am wondering, otherwise I might give a try to add the library to the Linker.

Comment: Thats weird that theres no Linker properties. Another thing you could just check is that libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib exists in your boost directory, I have had errors similar to yours where the compiler is looking for the .lib above, but the .lib in my boost directory was libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib ( notice the vc100 ).

Comment: I think the reason you are only seeing Common and Configuration properties is because you are viewing the properties for your solution, rather than the properties for your project within the solution! You need to right-click on your project name, which is usually located directly beneath the solution name.

Comment: @Paddyd yes you are right. 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib' does not exist in my 'lib' folder of Boost package. However, there exists a folder 'thread', which includes all the headers related with threading, in the 'boost' folder. What should I do now? Search for this particular .lib file in internet and copy it in the 'lib' folder? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wouldn't advise it. That would more than likely cause you more problems in the long run. Did you build the Boost library? The .libs should be generated once you have built it. It has been a while since I have built it myself, I will try and do it now and let you know if I get it working

Comment: it´s a little bit strange that it tries to link against libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib in the first place. msvc compiled libs are normally not prefixed with "lib". cmake should normally create a project that links against boost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib in this case. are you using find_package in your CMakeLists.txt to get the library name?

Comment: @Paddyd No, I did not built the boost library, rather, I used an alternative way. There exists pre-built binaries for Boost library. Here is the link: http://boost.teeks99.com/ From there I downloaded the required binaries, which in my case is 'boost_1_53_0-vc64-bin.exe' and along with that, I downloaded same version of Boost from boost.org. It suppose to work fine as per descriptions written in the website.

Comment: @user1283078 yes, I checked it out in teh CMakeLists.txt. There exists FIND_PACKAGE command. Here is the code:    FIND_PACKAGE (Boost COMPONENTS thread system date_time regex filesystem REQUIRED)
IF(NOT Boost_FOUND)
 MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Boost not found.")
ENDIF(NOT Boost_FOUND)

Comment: define these preprocessors: BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB and BOOST_AUTO_LINK_NOMANGLE